# Update Android OS programmatically

Tags: android

I am working on a Mobile Device Management Project. One of the requirements of our project is to update an Android device OS programmatically. The flow will be as follows:

1. Server sends push notification about OS update.
2. Android client downloads the updates.
3. Now I want to update Android device OS programmatically.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you got any sol can you please post it.I have this same requirement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to start system updates on normal non-rooted devices. System updates are delivered OTA only by Google and/or network providers.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply.

Comment: how to do for rooted device