# How to tell programatically if there's an OS upgrade available

Tags: android

Is it possible to tell from my app if there's an upgrade available to the Operating system? If so, can we tell what version is available?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696392/update-android-os-programmatically. May not be the exact answer you are looking for. But somewhat related to it. have a look

Comment: Every device has it's own custom method for firmware updates, most likely just a simple check of some website. So if you reverse engineer all of them you can probably tell from within your app if there is an update available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be done. There's no set API to determine when an upgrade is available because that functionality is dependent on the manufacturer, not Google.