# How can I upgrade the Android OS programmatically on a device with root access?

Tags: android, android-source, remote-management

Someone posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696392/update-android-os-programmatically), but it didn't get a response that's relevant to me. I'm working with a kiosk-like device that runs Android, and I'd like the ability to upgrade the OS remotely. I know Google and mobile carriers manage to do it OTA. Given that I have root privileges on the devices, how can I do the same?

Comment: This typically involves downloading some sort of install blob (typically a zip file) containing a script of instructions, and then re-booting into a recovery bootloader which will look for and process that.  You should find at least an (old/primitive) implementation in AOSP.  Note though that having "root access" does not by itself mean being able to write to the normally read-only flash partitions, as they can be locked below kernel level, too.

Comment: @Lappiton Did you find the answer? It's possible now for Android API level 24 and above using android.os.UpdateEngine. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bootable/recovery/+/master/updater_sample/